# Failure Message: Checkpoint expired before completing when using apache flink 1.11

Tags: apache-flink

I am upgrade my Apache Flink to version 1.11 recently in kubernetes cluster, but today I found one task checkpoint always failed. This task read data from RabbitMQ and caculate the result and invoke a HTTP request to save data to MySQL.This is the taskmanager error log output:

```
2020-08-21 15:53:28
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Exceeded checkpoint tolerable failure threshold.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointFailureManager.handleJobLevelCheckpointException(CheckpointFailureManager.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.abortPendingCheckpoint(CheckpointCoordinator.java:1626)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.abortPendingCheckpoint(CheckpointCoordinator.java:1603)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.access$600(CheckpointCoordinator.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator$CheckpointCanceller.run(CheckpointCoordinator.java:1736)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

and this is the Apache Flink UI error message:

```
Failure Message: Checkpoint expired before completing.
```

the job always restart in a period of time. I have 2 task and another task checkpoint keep success. so where is the problem and what should I do to fix this?

[image]

this is my flink  config:

```
 public static void initEnv(StreamExecutionEnvironment env) {
        env.setParallelism(1);
        env.enableCheckpointing(10000);
        env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
        env.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(1000);
        env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointTimeout(10000);
        env.getCheckpointConfig().setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1);
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
        env.getCheckpointConfig().enableExternalizedCheckpoints(CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
        StateBackend stateBackend = new FsStateBackend("file:///opt/flink/data");
        env.setStateBackend(stateBackend);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please specify what is the checkpoint timeout in your application ? I might be wrong, but from web ui it seems to be 10 seconds - could you please try to increase it to lets say 30 seconds and see whether it's able to complete or not ? thank you.

Comment: I have added my config into the question @MikalaiLushchytski

Comment: Could you please try to increase checkpoint timeout to 30 seconds ? It seems that it's not enough time for tasks to complete the checkpoint.

Comment: Also, checkpoints seems to be too frequent - every second. Do you need this level of granularity ?

Comment: Ok，I could tweak the checkpoint. I just do not know how long the checkpoint period could I set.@MikalaiLushchytski

Comment: You can set the checkpoint timeout to any value. Generally, this depends on the expected time required for operators to perform checkpoint - for example, in my experience we had a 2-minute checkpoint timeout in the applciation, writing to the external storages. This just sets the upper bound when the checkpoint got cancelled - if it completes in 15 seconds, then it's completely ok.

Comment: I increase the timeout and problem solved@MikalaiLushchytski

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to increase the timeout of checkpoint:

```
public static void initEnv(StreamExecutionEnvironment env) {
        env.setParallelism(1);
        env.enableCheckpointing(120000);
        env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
        env.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(1000);
        env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointTimeout(120000);
        env.getCheckpointConfig().setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1);
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
        env.getCheckpointConfig().enableExternalizedCheckpoints(CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
        StateBackend stateBackend = new FsStateBackend("file:///opt/flink/data");
        env.setStateBackend(stateBackend);
    }
```

Comment: thanks. for me was not only the `timeout` but locally I had to set the parallelism to `1` because I am doing checkpoint remotely and it is taking too much time when the parallelism was `16`.